# Limit of a $p$-adic function and L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, limits, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer and $\operatorname{val}_p$ be the $p$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Let $n$ be a natural number. My question is finding the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^k}{p^{\operatorname{val}_p(n!)}}.$$

I **guess** that this limit should be zero; because I **guess** that $\operatorname{val}_p(n!)$ is like $\dfrac{n}{p-1}$ for large $n$ (I know for sure that $\operatorname{val}_p(n!)$ is certainly less than $\dfrac{n}{p-1}$) and I apply the classical [L.Hopital's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) rule in calculus (although its not relevant to the $p$-adic case) to the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{x^k}{p^{x/(p-1)}}$ and by L.Hopital's rule, taking repeated derivatives, I get that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{x^k}{p^{x/(p-1)}}=0$ which gives me the feeling that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{n^k}{p^{\operatorname{val}_p(n!)}}=0$.

Thanks in advance for help and for explanations

Comment: There is nothing $p$-adic about your limit: it is the limit of an usual sequence of real numbers. And you cannot apply L'Hôpital's tule, as the denominator is not the result of evaluating a real function defined on an interval on integers.

Comment: I know I cannot apply L.Hopital. It was just for (a very bad guess). The quantity  $p^{-val}$ is the $p$-adic norm.

Comment: Are you trying to take this limit in the p-adic numbers or the real numbers?

Comment: Limit is over $n $ and it is in $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers.

Comment: Let me get this right. For a fixed $k$, you’re taking the (real) limit of $n^k|n!|_p$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$-adic valuation of $n!$ is classically known; see e.g. Artin-Tate's "Class Field Theory", beginning of chapter 12. Writing $n = a_0 + a_1 p + ... + a_r p^r$, where the coefficients $a_j$ are integers between $0$ and $p-1$, one has $v_p (n!) = (n-s_n)/(p-1)$ , where $s_n$ is the sum of the coefficients $a_j$. Since $v_p(n)= t+v_p(a_t)$, where $t$ is the smallest integer such that $a_t \neq 0$, the $p$-adic valuation of your quotient « behaves like » $kt – (n-s_n)/(p-1)$. It follows that your limit is actually $0$.

Comment: This is the same type of argument as mine. I will like a rigorous proof. For example as $n$ will go bigger, $t$ will go bigger.  Also $s_n $ will go to infinity. Your proof is not clear to me.

Comment: But when $n \to \infty, t \le r$ is negligible w.r.t. $p^{r-1}$  Similarly,  $s_n \le (p-1)(r+1)$ is negligible w.r.t. to $p^r$ . Edit: I see that  $s_n$ is missing in my last formula. I'll put it back.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.